# What do do with Notifications when UIApplicationStateActive

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.3

I have set up an app that is registered for remote notifications.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{    
    NSString *status = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Notification Received:\n%@",userInfo.description];
    NSLog(@"%@",status);

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] 
                        initWithTitle:@"didReceiveRemoteNotification" 
                        message:eventName
                        delegate:self 
                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Hide" 
                        otherButtonTitles:@"View", 
                        nil];
    alert.tag = kAlertTypeNotification;
    [alert show];
    [self vibrate];


if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive ) {
    // app was already in the foreground
    **DO SOMETHING HERE**

}
else {
    // app was just brought from background to foreground

}
}
```

So, when the app is not active, i get that really nifty banner alert, that looks so nice on the iPhone.

However, when the app is open, the only option I seem to have is to present a UIAlertView. This is intrusive in my opinion. Is there a way I can display the banner while application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive? Or, is there an open source library that implements this kind of feature?

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do whatever you want when the app is in the foreground. Who says you have to display a UIAlertView?

Comment: Well, I'm looking for a way to notify the user in a UIWebView without a UIAlertView. I feel like my options are limited to almost only a UIAlertView.

Something minimal like a banner at the top sounds great. However, I'm not sure if I can do that from when the app is active.

Answer (score 1):

I've asked this question more directly here:

[Displaying a stock iOS notification banner when your app is open and in the foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852870/displaying-a-stock-ios-notification-banner-when-your-app-is-open-and-in-the-fore/30855842#30855842)

The short answer is that as of iOS 9, you cannot show the **stock** iOS banner when your app is in the foreground.

You will instead have to rely on a home-built or 3rd-part notification banner.

Please duplicate this radar requesting this feature: rdar://22313177