# Push Local Notification when App Foreground in Swift, iOS 8,9

Tags: ios, swift, localnotification

In IOS10, I used UNMutableNotificationContent and set delegate,

```
private func pushNotification() {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "aaa"
    content.body = "bbb"
    content.subtitle = "00000"

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)

    let requestIdentifier = "com.aaaaa.bbbbb"

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
        if error == nil {
            print("Time Interval Notification scheduled: \\\\(requestIdentifier)")
        }
    }

}
```

send notification in foreground, the follows func was called
then i can show the notification in foregound by "completionHandler"

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Swift.Void) {
    completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
}
```

.
.
.

But in IOS8 & 9, i used UILocalNotification

```
private func pushNotification2() {

    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertAction = "Title Message"
    notification.alertBody = "Body Message"
    notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0) as Date
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.category = "INVITE_CATEGORY"


    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

}
```

and found these in AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {

}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, for notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, for notification: UILocalNotification, withResponseInfo responseInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
}
```

It's just called first func only when i send notification in foreground, but first func has no "completionHandler"
what should i do? thank your help

Answer (score 0):

Showing native notifications is not possible in iOS previous to iOS 10 as described in this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852870/displaying-a-stock-ios-notification-banner-when-your-app-is-open-and-in-the-fore).

If you need to support iOS 9, you will need to use one of the many third-party libraries that exist for this purpose.

[MDNotificationView](https://github.com/moritzdietsche/mdnotificationview) is one that I created. You could pass in a custom view that mimics the look of the native notifications in iOS.

```
// If you prefer to create your view with Interface Builder.
let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: bundle)
let views = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)

if 0 < views.count,
    let view = views[0] as? UIView {        

    let notificationView = MDNotificationView(view: view, position: .bottom)
    notificationView.delegate = self
    notificationView.show()
}
```

or

```
// If you prefer to create your view in code.
let view = YourCustomNotificationUIView()

let notificationView = MDNotificationView(view: view, position: .bottom)
notificationView.delegate = self
notificationView.show()
```

In addition, you can add the delegate methods:

```
// MARK: Notification View Delegate

func didTap(notificationView: MDNotificationView) {
}

func notificationDidShow(notificationView: MDNotificationView) {
}

func notificationDidHide(notificationView: MDNotificationView) {
}
```

Comment: MDNotificationView is not available anymore..can you please help me with MDNotificationView code.