# Alert coming in iOS 10 when pushnotification in foreground even when no alert code is written

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I am facing a strange issue in my iOS app. When my app is in foreground and Push is received it is displaying in notification center and also same is displayed in an alert.

But I have not written any alert displaying code in any of push notification received delegate methods in Appdelegate.

How to avoid this unwanted alertview when the app is in the foreground. ??

Answer (score 3):

It is due to the Delegate implemented

### Objective-C

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center 
                   willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification 
                     withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler {

             completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert); // SHOWS ALERT
}
```

### Swift 3

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(.alert)
}
```

In iOS 10 you can show notification also when is in foreground.
You can check by adding badge only in completionHandler or comment completionHandler

**Ref** : [Displaying a stock iOS notification banner when your app is open and in the foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852870/displaying-a-stock-ios-notification-banner-when-your-app-is-open-and-in-the-fore)