# Get local notification when App is in foreground Swift 4 iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I want to receive a Local notification when my app is in foreground, when I tried with below code it never fires a notification, but when I entered app in background it did fired.

here is what I tried:

```
//Schedule a Local Notification
func ScheduleNotification(timeInterval: Double, repeats: Bool, notificationBody:String, title:String){

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: repeats)

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    let identifier = "UYLLocalNotification"
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = title
    content.body = notificationBody
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            //Something went wrong
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if Currentcount < data.count {
        self.ScheduleNotification(timeInterval: 5.0, repeats: false, notificationBody: "You have \(data.count - Currentcount) notification", title: "Alert!")
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notification probably also fires while you app is in foreground.

Per Default, iOS does not show any UI when a notification arrives and the target app is in the foreground. It is the applications job to display the notification contents. Using `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` you can very easily display the notification as an alert. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37844312/4294969) for more information.

Comment: Do I need to add anything in viewDidLoad() method?

Answer (score 2):

**Here I am showing you how the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate is work step by step**

1. In the AppDelegate: `import UserNotifications`
2. `class AppDelegate: UIResponder,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{}`
3. Assign the delegate method to self inside the **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

   ```
   func application(_application:UIApplication,
   didFinishLaunchingWithOptionslaunchoptions:[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

          UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
               let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
               center.delegate = self        
               center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in

                   if granted {
                       DispatchQueue.main.async { // Correct
                           UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                       }

                   }

               }

       }
   ```
4. What you want to show in the Local Notification

   ```
        func assignValueToNotification
           {
               let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
               content.body = "Asssign body"
               content.userInfo = ["identifier": "info"]
               content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
               content.badge = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1 as NSNumber;
               content.categoryIdentifier = "write category identifier"
               // Deliver the notification in five seconds.
               let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false)
               let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: region.identifier as String, content: content, trigger: trigger)
              // Schedule the notification.
              let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
              center.add(request)
       }
   ```
5. write down you delegate method, that will be called when you click Local notification.

   ```
   func userNotificationCenter(_ center:UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response:UNNotificationResponse,withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void{
       print("Received Local Notification:")
   }
   ```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar or using Ctrl+K on your keyboard to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the `willPresent` delegate function of `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` to your `AppDelegate`.

Simply by giving `.sound, .banner` `UNNotificationPresentationOptions` into the completion handler, your local notifications will show when your app is in the foreground.

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.sound, .banner])
    }
}
```

One more step: You of course need to set the `UNUserNotificationCenter` delegate inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {  
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
}
```

### Note

For SwiftUI Cycles, you can access the AppDelegate like so:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62538373/8700044)