# Firebase initialisation in application delegate before StateObject initialisation

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, appdelegate

I am writing an app in SwiftUI and using Firebase as my backend.

I have a working preferences panel, that consists of a modal within the application itself, but am wanting to utilise macOS's consistent preferences window that includes the menu options as well as shortcut that is written about in [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/settings) article.

This is my App declaration and delegates.

```
@main
struct SchedulerApp: App {
    #if os(macOS)
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    #else
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    #endif
    
    @StateObject var authState = AuthState()
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .frame(minWidth: 800, minHeight: 450)
                .environmentObject(model)
                .environmentObject(authState)
            
        }
        .commands {
            SidebarCommands()
        }
        
        #if os(macOS)
        Settings {
            Preferences()
        }
        #endif
    }
}

#if os(macOS)
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
}
#else
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        
        
        return true
    }
}
#endif
```

You can see that I have both a delegate and a state object for an object that listens to the authentication state and another that holds user data and settings:

```
class AuthState: ObservableObject {
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    
    @Published var signedIn: Bool? = nil
    
    init() {
        listen()
    }
    
    func listen() {
        Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { [self] (auth, user) in
            switch user == nil {
            case true: signedIn = false
            case false: signedIn = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run this code, the following error occurs:

> The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization. Read more: (...)

> The default FIRApp instance must be configured before the default FIRAuthinstance can be initialized. One way to ensure that is to call `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) in the App Delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in Swift).

I need the app to have a singular source of truth at the initialisation step - but the applicationWillFinishLaunching for some reason is calling after the StateObject call.

My app currently has these StateObject classes declared in ContentView, which dodges these errors, but as I mentioned above, I need preferences to share a single source of truth.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in [Where to configure Firebase in my iOS app in the new SwiftUI App life cycle without AppDelegate and SceneDelegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62626652), you can either use your app's initialiser (`init()`) or an `AppDelegate` to initialise Firebase.

Using the initialiser works for quite a few of Firebase's SDKs, but there are some that make use of method swizzling, and they expect the presence of an `AppDelegate`.

In [The Ultimate Guide to the SwiftUI 2 Application Life Cycle - SwiftUI 2](https://peterfriese.dev/ultimate-guide-to-swiftui2-application-lifecycle/), I dive into some of the details of the new app life cycle.

Let's take a look at the code for the [sample app](https://github.com/peterfriese/Colors) I built for that article, and the resulting output:

```swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    print("Colors application is starting up. ApplicationDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.")
    return true
  }
}


@main
struct ColorsApp: App {
  @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
  
  @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
  
  init() {
    print("Colors application is starting up. App initialiser.")
  }
  
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
    }
    .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newScenePhase in
      switch newScenePhase {
      case .active:
        print("App is active")
      case .inactive:
        print("App is inactive")
      case .background:
        print("App is in background")
      @unknown default:
        print("Oh - interesting: I received an unexpected new value.")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Debug console output:

```
Colors application is starting up. App initialiser.
Colors application is starting up. ApplicationDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
App is active
```

So the app initialisation happens as follows:

1. The app initialiser is called
2. The `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called
3. The `scenePhase` changes to `.active`

For your app, I'd recommend the following:

1. Initialise Firebase in your app's initialiser
2. In your app's initialiser, initialise your models and other sources of truth, and connect them to the respective Firebase services

Another option is:

1. Initialise Firebase in your app's initialiser
2. Initialise your models and sources of truths by providing default values (as you did), but don't connect to Firebase just yet
3. Implement a `ScenePhase` handler and - once the app goes into `.active` state, "activate" your models and tell them to connect to Firebase.

The first option sounds a lot cleaner and easier to implement. to me :-)

Answer (score 2):

Within SchedulerApp: App just add an init to initialize Firebase. You would no longer need the AppDelegate class (unless your going to do other stuff in there later).

```
 init() { 
    FirebaseApp.configure()
 }
```