# How to get NSView from SwiftUI2 App entry

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm migrating my macOS app built with SwiftUI 1 to SwiftUI 2. There is a feature that allows user to save the main view as pdf using `NSPrinterOperation`, which takes an `NSView` instance.

Currently, the app is on SwiftUI 1 with `AppDelegate`, and I can get the main view through this code

```swift
Button("Print") {
   let appDelegate = NSApp.delegate as! AppDelegate
   let view = appDelegate.window.contentView! // returns the NSHostingView set up in AppDelegate.swift
   ...
   NSPrintOperation(view: view, printInfo: newInfo).run()
}
```

Since upgrading to SwiftUI2, the `AppDelegate` is no longer there, and how can I get the view now?

Comment: This topic [SwiftUI life-cycle iOS14 Where to put AppDelegate code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62538373/12299030) should be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment for reference how to set app delegate (which you will be able then access), however also you can content view directly from window via `NSApp`, like

```
NSApp.mainWindow?.contentView
```

or

```
NSApp.keyWindow?.contentView
```

depending on your windows configuration.