# Supporting different Lifecycle methods in same multiplatform(iOS, macOS, watchOS, tvOS) app

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios13, appdelegate, ios14

This [SwiftUI-Kit](https://github.com/jordansinger/SwiftUI-Kit) is a open source project, which acts as a way for showcasing all SwiftUI components and it supports all Apple platforms.

The project was created in Xcode 12 beta, with the new SwiftUI `App` protocol for handling the app's lifecycle and the deployment target being iOS 14.

Now, I want to add Support for iOS 13 to the project. And I can't find a way to have both `App` protocol for iOS 14 and other platforms and use `AppDelegate` for iOS 13 in this project.

I tried different combinations of App Delegate and Scene Delegate methods. The end result is a crash in iOS 13 device with the following error.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI4ViewPAAE18navigationBarTitle_11displayModeQrqd___AA010NavigationE4ItemV0f7DisplayH0OtSyRd__lFQOMQ
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0813D699-9718-4106-BBC6/SwiftUI Kit iOS.app/SwiftUI Kit iOS
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI
 in /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0813D699-9718-4106-BBC6/SwiftUI Kit iOS.app/SwiftUI Kit iOS
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
```

Here is the code. You can find full project code for iOS 13 in [this branch](https://github.com/SwiftUIApps/SwiftUI-Kit/tree/iOS13).

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

#if os(iOS)

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {...}

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // ...
        let contentView = ContentView()

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {...}

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {...}

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {...}

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {...}

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {...}
}

@main
struct MainApp {
    static func main() {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            SwiftUI_Kit_iOS_App.main()
        } else {
            UIApplicationMain(
                CommandLine.argc,
                CommandLine.unsafeArgv,
                nil,
                NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
            )
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 14.0, *)
struct SwiftUI_Kit_iOS_App: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

#else

@main
struct SwiftUI_KitApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            #if os(macOS)
            ContentView().frame(minWidth: 100, idealWidth: 300, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, idealHeight: 200, maxHeight: .infinity)
            #else
            ContentView()
            #endif
        }
    }
}

#endif
```

I looked up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62538110/swiftui-life-cycle-ios14-where-to-put-appdelegate-code), but the answers require iOS 14 as target. I want to make it work with iOS 13 as target.

Comment: You cannot use SwiftUI Life-cycle on pre-iOS14, the same as you cannot use SwiftUI on pre-iOS13.

Comment: @Asperi I'm not trying to use SwiftUI Life-cycle on pre iOS 14, I just want to know how to use both in the same project, supporting different targets.

Comment: Hm, I just came across an article about that! https://swiftui-lab.com/backward-compatibility/

Comment: @cbjeukendrup Thanks for the link. It is working with iOS 14. But I'm still getting the same crash in iOS 13.

Comment: I believe you can't have two `@main` attributes, maybe that is the point. But your case is a little more complex, because you want to support multiple platforms. I will have a closer look and let you know!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I finally found a solution!

No, it's not beautiful, and no, it's not nice, but it's quite correct and it works as far as I can check. So, here it is:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MainApp {
    static func main() {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, macOS 11.0, tvOS 14.0, watchOS 7.0, *) {
            SwiftUIApp.main()
        } else {
            #if os(iOS) // iOS 13.0 or lower
            UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc,
                              CommandLine.unsafeArgv,
                              nil,
                              NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self))
            #else
            // So we are on macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0 or someting lower.
            // By correctly setting the deployment target in your project,
            // you won't need to do someting here, as this situation will
            // never occur.
            print("This app doesn't run (yet) on this OS, so Bye")
            return
            #endif
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 14.0, macOS 11.0, tvOS 14.0, watchOS 7.0, *)
struct SwiftUIApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        return WindowGroup {
            #if os(macOS)
            ContentView().frame(minWidth: 100, idealWidth: 300, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, idealHeight: 200, maxHeight: .infinity)
            #else
            ContentView()
            #endif
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello world!")
    }
}

#if os(iOS)
import UIKit
// @UIApplicationMain <- remove that!
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        return true
    }
    
    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }

}

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        let contentView = ContentView()

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) { /*...*/ }
    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) { /*...*/ }
    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) { /*...*/ }
    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) { /*...*/ }
    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) { /*...*/ }
}
#endif
```

Quite a lot of code, huh?

But, (in my case) this was not all. We also need to dive into the Info.plist file for the iOS target.

1. Find the key called `Application Scene Manifest` or `UIApplicationSceneManifest` and expand it (by clicking the gray triangle)
2. Add the following things so that it looks like in the picture below:
   [image: Info.plist]

   Make sure that at "Default configuration" you fill in exactly the same as in this line of the code:

   ```
           return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
   ```

   Furthermore, "SceneDelegate" should be the name of the `SceneDelegate` class and "LaunchScreen" should be the name of your launch screen storyboard (sometimes it's written with a space, sometimes without, so be careful!).

   If you use the code I provided, and don't rename one of these things, this won't probably be a problem.
3. Finally, delete the app from the device. This will make sure that the new Info.plist is copied when re-running and installing. (only necessary when making changes in Info.plist)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However, I am getting the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error at the line, where you have called `UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, ...)`.

Comment: Oh, that's not a good sign... and I don't immediately have a solution. You could try pressing Cmd+Shift+K to 'clean' the project and then run again. Sometimes that helps.

Comment: I have cleaned the project multiple times. Restarted Xcode, Mac and Phone. Nothing worked.

Comment: I will try what I can do!

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. It seems that you don't actually use Main.storyboard, so maybe it's a good idea to delete it. Make sure that the "Main interface" field in `Project -> SwiftUI Kit iOS -> Deployment Info` is empty. 2. There was a typo in the Info.plist file for iOS: `LaunchScren` instead of `LaunchScreen`. Maybe one of these things helps?

Comment: Thanks for you efforts, but I have to report that I'm facing crash at the same line.