# How to change the stylemask of NSWindow using Xcode12

Tags: swiftui, xcode12

On the subject of MacApp, is there a way to change it with the SwiftUI App on Xcode12?

I know how to change it with AppKit App Delegate.

Comment: The following can be helpful [SwiftUI life-cycle iOS14 Where to put AppDelegate code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62538373/12299030)

Comment: @Asperi I know it is possible to change the stylemask by using AppDelegate and applicationDidFinishLanching.
However, if I use "window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)" like AppKit App Delegate, two windows appear and var body: some Scene is not passed ContentView will be launched.
We want to change the NSWindow using the .commands added in xcode12.
Sorry for the poor explanation.