# How to generate a Combine Publisher for didReceiveRemoteNotification?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I am trying to generate a Combine publisher off `didReceiveRemoteNotification`

Similar to this code below:

```
NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)
```

I want to use SwiftUI Lifecycle and don't want to use AppDelegate methods using `@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor`

Comment: No. NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didReceiveRemoteNotification) throws error. => Type 'UIApplication' has no member 'didReceiveRemoteNotification'

Comment: There isn't a notification that is posted when a remote notification is received.  You will need to implement the app delegate method and send on the publisher from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Notification` named `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, but you can declare it in an extension on `UIApplication`:

```
extension UIApplication {
    static let didReceiveRemoteNotification = Notification.Name("didReceiveRemoteNotification")
}
```

Then you need to post the `Notification` from the `AppDelegate`:

```
extension AppDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: UIApplication.didReceiveRemoteNotification,
                                        object: nil)
        
        // etc...
    }
    
}
```

That will allow you to use the usual syntax:

```
NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didReceiveRemoteNotification)
```