# Pre-populate data with SwiftUI 2.0 and Core Data

Tags: core-data, swiftui

How can I pre-populate data from a json into core data in SwiftUI 2.0 when the app is loaded only for the first time. In SwiftUI 1.0 I did it in the `AppDelegate.swift` but there is no such file anymore.

Comment: There are quite a few parts to this question - decoding JSON, doing something when app first loads (use `UserDefaults` or similar to track this), and working with CoreData. You should probably focus the question on one thing, like just about CoreData with SwiftUI 2 app lifecycle

Comment: AppDelegate is still there - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62538110/swiftui-app-life-cycle-ios14-where-to-put-appdelegate-code/62538373#62538373

Answer (score -1):

Add your own `AppDelegate.swift`

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey :    Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Then in your `@main` `View` add.

```
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
```

for iOS or

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        
    }
    
}
```

and

```
@NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
```

for MacOS