# There is no Scene and App delegate in Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

It seems there is no scene delegate in the latest swift ui version. Can anyone help me set my root page of my application please?

Thank you from now on.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62538373/12299030?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI app life cycle iOS14 where to put AppDelegate code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62538110/swiftui-app-life-cycle-ios14-where-to-put-appdelegate-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new file and provide root view like this:

```
import SwiftUI
@main
struct YourAppName: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView() <- root page
        }
    }
}
```