# iOS How to display local notification in foreground?

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

Is there a way to post and show  local notifications in the foreground?
If not, is there a way to "fake it"?
I need to make an iOS appear like an Android app, which does have notifications in the foreground.

Answer (score 3):

For iOS 10 and next you can use [UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate) and see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37844312/4294969) for more information. If you app run on 8 or 9 ios you should use 3d party libs (you can [search](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=notification))

**Sample:**
Add it to your delegate methods in the AppDelegate and conform to this protocol - UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
     completionHandler([.alert,.badge])
}
```