# how to get push notification when app is open?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, unusernotificationcenter

I am working on swift 4.2.I am getting notifications when app is background but i am not getting when app is active.

```swift
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

I would like to know how to get a notification when the app is open

Comment: Why do you think you don't get it? it just not displayed. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852870/displaying-a-stock-ios-notification-banner-when-your-app-is-open-and-in-the-fore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to confirm UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate in your AppDelegate class;

```
import UserNotifications

class AppDelegate : UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

   }
```

then you can call this function in your ViewController class, don forget to import UserNotifications again in ViewController;

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) 
{
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

Comment: You are most wellcome :)

Answer (score 0):

update this code with above mentioned code

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler:
        @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("Handle push from foreground")
        print("\(notification.request.content.userInfo)")
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])

        return
    }
```