# Can not show a notification when the app becomes active

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I need to show a local notification whenever the app becomes active. The problem is when I schedule notification from inside `scenePhase` is `.active` it is not scheduled and nothing shows but I can schedule it successfully from inside `onAppear()`.
My code is:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var notificationManager: NotificationManager
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase

      var body: some View {
          SomeView()
            .onAppear() {
                // from here the notification is scheduled and sent correctly
                // scheduleNotification()
            }
            .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newScenePhase in
                if newScenePhase == .active {  // App is becoming active
                    // from here the notification is not scheduled and never sent
                    scheduleNotification()
                }
            }
    }

    func scheduleNotification() {
        notificationManager.sendNotification(id: "BackgroundTask", title: "Background Task", body: "Scheduled successfully", soundName: "Announce", timeInterval: 1)
    }
}
```

So, why the notification is not scheduled when I call it from scenePhase is active.

**Update:**

As soundflix mentioned in its comment to make my question clear I am adding the `NotificationManager` class

```
@MainActor
class NotificationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification) async -> UNNotificationPresentationOptions {
        return [.sound, .banner]
    }
    
    func sendNotification(id: String, title: String, body: String, soundName: String, timeInterval: TimeInterval) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = title
        content.body = body
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName("\(soundName).wav"))
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: false)
        let req = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: id, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(req, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include code for `NotificationManager`, we can not know what it does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying a stock iOS notification banner when your app is open and in the foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852870/displaying-a-stock-ios-notification-banner-when-your-app-is-open-and-in-the-fore)

Comment: @soundflix No this does not answer my question, I can show the notification when the app is in the foreground (as I mentioned in my question if I called my function `scheduleNotification` from inside `onAppear` the notification shows when the app becomes in foreground) but as you know if the app is already opened and left in the background then open it again to come from background to foreground the `onAppear` is not calling and that is why I need to use `scenePhase` to call my function `scheduleNotification` every time the app comes to the foreground.

Comment: @soundflix I updated the question to include `NotificationManager` class